# Getting x,y values from two for loops python

Tags: python

I am trying to append numbers from two for loops to make some tuples and add them to a list.

```
li = []
for x in range(1,10):
    for y in range(1,10):
        li.append((x,y*2))
print(li)
```

I am getting this

```
[(1, 2), (1, 4), (1, 6), (1, 8), (1, 10), (1, 12), (1, 14), (1, 16), (1, 18), (2, 2), (2, 4), (2, 6), (2, 8), (2, 10), (2, 12), (2, 14), (2, 16), (2, 18), (3, 2), (3, 4), (3, 6), (3, 8), (3, 10), (3, 12), (3, 14), (3, 16), (3, 18), (4, 2), (4, 4), (4, 6), (4, 8), (4, 10), (4, 12), (4, 14), (4, 16), (4, 18), (5, 2), (5, 4), (5, 6), (5, 8), (5, 10), (5, 12), (5, 14), (5, 16), (5, 18), (6, 2), (6, 4), (6, 6), (6, 8), (6, 10), (6, 12), (6, 14), (6, 16), (6, 18), (7, 2), (7, 4), (7, 6), (7, 8), (7, 10), (7, 12), (7, 14), (7, 16), (7, 18), (8, 2), (8, 4), (8, 6), (8, 8), (8, 10), (8, 12), (8, 14), (8, 16), (8, 18), (9, 2), (9, 4), (9, 6), (9, 8), (9, 10), (9, 12), (9, 14), (9, 16), (9, 18)]
```

But it should only be a single x per y combination. How do I fix this?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: The guy answered so fast I had to wait before marking the answer and then I just forgot, apologies

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using list comprehension:

```
>>> [(x, x**2) for x in range(1, 10)]
[(1, 1), (2, 4), (3, 9), (4, 16), (5, 25), (6, 36), (7, 49), (8, 64), (9, 81)]
```

using `for` loop:

```
>>> li = []
>>> for x in range(1, 10):
...     li.append((x, x**2))
... 
>>> li
[(1, 1), (2, 4), (3, 9), (4, 16), (5, 25), (6, 36), (7, 49), (8, 64), (9, 81)]
```

Comment: yes exactly that. So my problem was instead of two for loops, I should have just done a list comprehension. Guess that's what list comprehensions are for! Thank you

Comment: but how can you append these values into an empty list now that they have been generated?

Answer (score 1):

If you have no problems using third party libraries as NumPy, you can also do the following avoiding any explicit `for` loops.

P.S: For your small example, it might be an overkill but it's good to know alternatives.

The [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip) here returns an iterator of tuples based on the iterable objects fed as input.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(1, 10)
print (list(zip(x, x**2)))

# [(1, 1), (2, 4), (3, 9), (4, 16), (5, 25), (6, 36), (7, 49), (8, 64), (9, 81)]
```